# wifi terribly slow and unreliable, then works fine after few restarts

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a bizarre wifi problem on my new lenovo laptop (Qualcomm QCNFA765 / ath11k_pci).

Most of the time, the wifi connection is terribly slow and unreliable. One ping might me 3 ms, and next might me 200 ms:

[image]

but sometimes, rarely, when I start the laptop, everything is fine and pings are consistently 2.5 ms

[image]

without me changing absolutely anything

Right now, it happens to work fine. What should I check to determine why now it works fine, but othertimes not ?

Also, when the connection is terrible, it is not due to my router. because I have other laptops and they work fine all the time.

I do have  Power Management disabled:

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'Power Management'
      Power Management:off
```

Comment: Are all clients using the same 802.? standard? I've seen exactly this for routers having to simultaneously handle clients on different standards, when certain combinations arise. If you can for a moment have just that computer connected, you might be able to confirm if the problem persists.